# How to make a reverse relate between two models in one application?

Tags: django, django-models

How to make a reverse relate between two models in one application?

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    user_status = models.ForeignKey(Status)


class Status(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django does it automatically for you. So you should not specify it as a field on the related model.

Remove the `ManyToManyField` on `Status`. Then, if you have a `Status` object, you can reference the reverse relationship with `status.user_set.all()`. Or, you can add a `related_name` to the `ForeignKey`, you can use a custom name:

```
user_status = models.ForeignKey(Status, related_name="users", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

Note that I added `on_delete` since that's required in Django 2.x forces you to specify what should happen if the `Status` is deleted.

```
status = Status.objects.first()
status.users.all()  # all users for that status
```

Comment: I need to the admin page to also have a select (ForeignKey mb), that would refer to all records from the Status model

Comment: That's what you'll get automatically, you don't have to do anything. A `ForeignKey` will show up in the admin as a pull-down list of all possible objects from the related model.

Comment: why? can a user have multiple statuses?

Comment: You did not understand.
I have a `class Status`. It should have a field `user_status` that refers to the `class User` (**MTM**).
In the `User class` there is a `status field`. It must refer to the `Status class` (**FK**).

Comment: The problem is that both classes are located in the same application (`accounts`).

Comment: If you do what you say, a user will have 2 status fields: the `status` foreign key and a `status_set` with all statuses that have a m2m relationship to that user. Is that really what you need? I think you’re misunderstanding FK and M2M.

Comment: I understand what you are driving at ...
Maybe you are right.

In general, it is necessary that the Status model contains a list of all users.
I just wanted to have a status field in each user record where their status would be displayed ..
It seems I understood. I need to link these fields through the signal, and make the user_status field in the User model - readonly.

Comment: So as I said. You should not specify the field explicitly on `Status`. It’s already there through the reverse relationship as I show in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the statuses for a user with `status_set`:

```
user = User.objects.first()
user.status_set.all() # get all status of a user
```

You can assign another name to the reverse with the `related_name` argument:

```
class Status(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='states')


user = User.objects.first()
user.states.all()
```

[Many to many official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: I need to the admin page to also have a select (`ForeignKey`), that would refer to all records from the `Status` model.

Comment: But do you want one or two relations? In the question you have two relations a ForeingKey and a ManyToMany. In the admin you can have a select to set the value of `user_status` but that value does not have any relation with the field `users` of the `Status` model.

Comment: See my coment at answer above.